# Spring Batch scaling and redundancy in a multi server (cluster) environment

Tags: spring-batch

I want to implement a Spring Batch in a multi server (cluster) environment, thereby using the scaling and redundancy aspects of that multi server configuration.

Each incoming file triggers a job with step A, B, C, D and E. More than 1 job may be processed in parallel, except for step D. Even if multiple jobs are running, step D should run only 1 instance a the same time.

How can I configure that multiple jobs may run at the same time on different servers and how to configure that step D is a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

I'd structure your jobs so that D is independent from the others and use a message from the others to launch D.  With that approach you can do things to filter out duplicate messages from the other jobs trying to launch D, thereby making sure it is only launched once.